# Template Errors with Include on Single Entry

Tags: templating, error-message, include

Now I've run into a really odd issue. I've got a hero include that is working elsewhere on the site, but on this one single it's not working at all. On a working "Single" the code is this

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}


{% include '_includes/hero'
  with {
    imageName : 'page-hero-about',
    className : 'about',
    imageAlt  : 'Photo of store front',
    findStore : false,
    leadCols  : 'col-md-6',
    leadClass : 'lead'
  }
%}
```

And on the other non-working single the code is this:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}

    {#{% set entry = craft.entries.id(72) %} #}

    {% include '_includes/hero'
      with {
          imageName : 'page-hero-mission',
          className : 'mission',
          imageAlt  : 'Teaching people to read',
          findStore : false,
          leadCols  : 'col-md-9',
          leadClass : ''
     }
%}
```

On the non working page if I don't set the entry id I get a variable "entry" does not exist (though this is not needed on the working single). However once I do set that I get this error `Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string` Have googled but can't seem to find anything.  Also the code is pretty much identical so am at a loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, the `entry` variable is actually an instance of [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), which is probably the reason you're getting errors.

In order to set `entry` to an actual [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel), you'll need to add a call to `first()`:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(72).first() %}
...
```

Comment: That solves it. Thank you. But why does the other template not require me to set the entry?

Comment: I'm guessing that the other template is the _Entry Template_ for that particular Single section, in which case Craft will automatically populate the `entry` variable with the correct entry for you. Perhaps you can set the not-working template as the Entry Template for your other Single … in which case the above isn't neccessary. Just pop open the relevant Section via Settings -> Sections, and add the appropriate template path to "Entry Template" field.